# Minimalistic schedular

Tags: plugins

I've been looking at schedulers and appointment maker plugins the last few days, but so far haven't found anything suitable. So thought I'd ask, Basically I just want to be able to list a loads of dates for scheduling games and practices in the admin section and then to display say the next 5 - 10 games and practices on the home page in their own little discreet section/sidebar/widget. Something like this is what I'm after at this site hcusoccer.ca/ at the bottom on the right.

Does anyone know of anything that may be good? Everything i've come across so far is probably a bit to big and advanced. Does anybody have any good ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/screenshots/

Comment: Thanks for that, It's as close as I think I could of hoped for. Jonny